# How to define new derived properties when extending an AmpersandJS base library of models and collections?

Tags: inheritance, backbone.js, ampersand.js

I have reviewed the following documentation which demonstrates this technique with AmpersandViews:
https://ampersandjs.com/learn/base-objects-and-mixins/

It is kind of working for me with models and collections, however, I am not able to define any new derived properties by further extending the base models/collections in my native web app. If they are created through fetch(), the derived properties are 'undefined'.  However, if I create them locally, they work as expected. See snippet below for a breakdown of my code. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong? Or, if this is intended behavior, are there any workarounds? (I'm including a Backbone.js tag in this since Backbone and Ampersand are so closely related and use the same sync/fetch method.)

```js
//****************
// app.js (entry page)
//****************
import app from 'ampersand-app'
import Manifest from './manifest'
import Me from './me'

window.app = app

app.extend({
  init () {
    this.me = new Me( {id:123, login:'bob'} )
    this.me.fetchInitialData()
  }
})

app.init()

var m = new Manifest( { _id: 'foo', '@id': 'bar', label: [{ '@value': 'Manifest 1'}] } )

document.write(m.app_url) //--> works!

/* After bundled with webpack and initial data is fetched, the following returns undefined in the console:
app.me.presentations.manifests.models[0].app_url
*/


//****************
// me.js
//****************
import Model from 'ampersand-model'
import {Collections} from 'tabula-rasa'

export default Model.extend({

  children: {
    presentations: Collections
  },


  fetchInitialData () {

      this.presentations.fetch()

  }

})
  
//****************
// collections.js 
//****************
import {Collections} from 'tabula-rasa'
import ManifestList from './manifest-collection'

export default Collections.Collection.extend({

  collections: {
    manifests: ManifestList,
  },

  derived: {
    app_url: {
      deps: ['_id'],
      fn () {
        return 'collections/' + this._id
      }
    }
  }
  
// manifest-collection.js
import {ManifestList} from 'tabula-rasa'
import Manifest from './manifest'

export default ManifestList.extend({

  model: Manifest

})

})

//****************
// manifest.js
//****************
import {Manifest} from 'tabula-rasa'

export default Manifest.extend({

  derived: {
    app_url: {
      deps: ['_id'],
      fn () {
        return 'manifests/' + this._id
      }
    }
  }

})
```

(Edited to add code to the question rather than point to an external GitHub project. Due to npm module dependencies snippet will not run.)

Comment: You should add the minimal code (*not a link to code*) required to reproduce the issue **in** question... read [mcve]

Comment: Ah, @TJ, thanks for the tip... that would explain the downvotes.  I have solved this.  I will update the question with minimal code and list the answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I was including the original base library Collections module in me.js.  Replacing this:

```
import {Collections} from 'tabula-rasa'
```

with this (my extended model):

```
import Collections from './collections'
```

... in me.js did the trick.